# Windows SBS 2008 and Exchange Move to external provider. MSSTD

Tags: windows, exchange, windows-sbs-2008

We have recently moved our exchange from out internal server (Windows SBS 2008) to an external provider for various reasons.

However when we now set-up our new email accounts, no matter what setting we enter in the "Exchange Proxy Settings" window, it get's reset back to our old domain.

I wonder if anyone knows of a way to stop this, (Turning off Exchange is a n option, so if anyone can advise that would be great)

Screen shot below showing the screen where the settings change.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain joined Outlook clients are going to query AD for the service connection point for the Exchange Autodiscover URL and then are going to connect to Exchange based on the information in the XML file located at that URL. I'm not sure why they'd still be doing this if you've configured them manually but there are a number of ways I can think of to get around this:

1. Remove the Autodiscover XML file
2. Remove the SCP (service connection point) information from AD using ADSIEDIT
3. Remove the Autodiscover virtual directory in IIS

The easiest and least destructive method and the easiest to reverse if needed is to remove the autodiscover XML file. The next easiest method would be to remove the SCP information from AD, and the least preferred method would be to remove the Autodiscover virtual directory in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

The Exchange 2007 Autodiscover Service is changing the parameter. To correct you need to change the Client Access Outlook Anywhere settings in your local Exchange.

Exchange Management Console (EMC) > Server Configuration > Client Access > [servername] > Properties > Outlook Anywhere - Enter correct external exchange proxy server name and client authentication method.

Comment: That setting is related to the external URL of the *this* server (the SBS server) that external Outlook clients will connect to. The OP is not using *this* server anymore. He's connecting to an external email provider.

Comment: Yes but his local Exchange is still up and therefore the local clients are using the SCP to get the url for the autodiscover service. The local autodiscover service is then returning the url for the local Outlook Anywhere. By changing this setting autodiscover will now return the url for the external hosted Outlook Anywhere which should fic his client settings being overwritten with the local Outlook Anywhere.